# array in node.js socket.io deleting socket ids on its own?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, sockets

i have a small test application with node.js and socket.io. here is the connection and disconnection:

```
// all necessary files
var connectedsockets = new Array();

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('set username', function(userName) {
    connectedsockets.push(socket.id);
 // inserting some info

});



socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log("disconnected socket "+socket.id);
    var index = connectedsockets.indexOf(socket.id);
    connectedsockets.splice(index,1);
    var sizea=connectedsockets.length;
    console.log(sizea+" left");
    });
 });
```

Most of the time the connection/disconnection works fine, but sometimes even the sockets which are open seem to be deleted from the connectedsockets array. What could be the problem? i am connecting to the server via https.

Comment: Are the connections which are disappearing actually having their `set username` event handled and getting pushed?

Comment: yeah.. the connections work for a period of time and then suddenly disappear from the array when other connections are connecting/disconnecting

Comment: Is that your real code?  `socket` isn't in scope when you do `socket.on('disconnect'...`, so I'm not sure how its working at all.

Comment: ohh sorry.. my mistake. those }); dont exist there. just edited it

Comment: Why don't you use io.sockets.clients() variable?